# How to Detect Enter key in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to detect **Enter Key**. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<input name="txtTest"  type="text" id="txtTest" onkeyup="CheckKey()"/>
```

Javascript

```
function CheckKey()
{
    var e = window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(code === 13)
    {
      alert("You press Enter key.");
    }            
}
```

This code is working in other browsers but not in Firefox Why?
Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3PSe/2/)

**Please provide answers using javascript only.**

Comment: `window.event` is only available in IE. You have to pass the `event` in the `inline` call - that way all browsers will have it available in the callback.

Comment: @Ian Nicely noted. `=]` I also thought `window.event` was IE-proprietary, but apparently Chrome is adopting a lot of non-standard Microsoft-proprietary stuff to don't break compatibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you have to pass the `event` object to the handler:

```
<input name="txtTest"  type="text" id="txtTest" onkeyup="CheckKey(event)"/>
<!--                                            passes event object ^   -->
```

```js
function CheckKey(e) //receives event object as parameter
{
   var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if(code === 13)
   {
       alert("You press Enter key.");
   }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wkpeq/1)

Comment: I am new to jsFiddle. Please tell me how to chose only javascript in jsFiddle.

Comment: @user1390378 Sorry, not exactly sure what you meant. Do you mean the "No-Library (Pure JS)" option in the top-left of the page? Or, if you mean to view only the JS panel, then I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

**You should separate JavaScript code from HTML.**

Try something like this - key should work on all browsers:

```
<input type="text" id="txtTest" onkeyup="CheckKey(e)"/>

function CheckKey(e) {
   var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
   if(key === 13)
   {
       alert("You press Enter key.");
   }
}
```

Or as suggested with jQuery (separated JavaScript code from HTML) - use [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/):

```
   <!--HTML file e.g. index.html-->
   <input type="text" id="txtTest" />

    //JavaScript file e.g. script.js - you have to include that script in your HTML file
    $(function(){
      $('#txtTest').on('keyup', function(e){
          if(e.which === 13)
          {
            alert("You press Enter key.");
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Provide an answer that is based on the original question first :) I don't see any jQuery being used. And at least use what jQuery offers - `e.which` - there's no need for checking `e.charCode`/`e.keyCode` when jQuery normalizes it. If you want to provide an unobtrusive Javascript approach, it's with `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`

Comment: I see now. Hes jsFiddle got jQuery included.

Comment: Hmm good point, didn't see that. I wonder if the OP even realizes it. Anyways, `e.which` is still what you should use for `key`

Comment: @lan I am new to jsFiddle. Please tell me how to chose javascript in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode`!

```
function CheckKey(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)